# Applications of the dual linear program in optimisation methods

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

Which optimisation algorithms use or rely on the dual of a linear program?

I know that Benders decomposition uses the dual of the subproblem to derive additional constraints, but I would like to find more examples.

Comment: Have a look into the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm (max-flow, min-cut).

Comment: dual simplex, network simplex, robust optimization, interior point methods